# How do I get git branch name autocompletion working in Oh My Zsh?

Tags: git, zsh, oh-my-zsh

My coworker said it should work out of the box. I've also installed the git autocomplete for zsh. Any ideas on how to debug this?

Comment: I don't use zsh, so I can't help there - but maybe check if the autocomplete script that you've added to your bash profile equivalent works in any other shells to see if the problem is specific to zsh?

Comment: Its a zsh specific script

Comment: Do you have bash-completion installed as well? Oh-my-zsh doesn't need a separate git plugin. Log out of the terminal and login again and it should just work like your coworker stated

Comment: Just add *git* to *plugins* portion of your **.zshrc**: `plugins=(git brew)` and it should work.

Comment: @dNitro that didnt work

Comment: Have you sourced your `.zshrc` file since adding these scripts?

Comment: Yes I did @IanAuld